# Pattern matching and replacement in oracle

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching, replace

So we have a table called TEMPLATES that stores html email templates as plain text (don't ask, I wasn't around when that decision was made). There are a number of columns in this table but the one we care is the TEMPLATE field which is where the text is stored.

Now we recently updated the libraries used by the server to parse these templates before they get sent to the user. These libraries use a new syntax for variables

```
${varName}
```

My problem is a lot of the old email templates use the old syntax

```
@varName@
```

These variable names contain only alpha-numeric characters. I'm trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace all instances of `@whateverVariable@` with `${whateverVariable}` but I'm having difficulty preserving the variable name when I do the replacement. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I should probably mention the field is a CLOB if that makes a difference.

Comment: CLOB or VARCHAR2 makes no difference (here) ([ORACLE DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm)), use a simple UPDATE like `UPDATE TEMPLATES set template = REPLACE(template,'@whateverVariable@','${newVariable}');` , REGEXP_REPLACE is a little bit too heavy for this job and you know your variableNames.

Comment: @Patrick7 Yeah, but I'm trying to run one one script that will fix all variables regardless of the actual variable name. I don't know all the variable names, nor do I want to run the script each time for every variable in every template.

Comment: Do you think that showing your regular expression, along with the current and expected results, might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables have a fixed format and 3 parts:

- the opening `@`
- variable name
- the closing `@`

With the below regexp, you can keep the 2nd part (`\2`) and add the extra characters around it you need (`${ }`):

```
with data as
(
  select 
    to_clob('@ @@ ABC @variable1@ DEF @something2@ GHI @variable3@ @@@')
      as template 
  from dual
)
select 
  template,
  regexp_replace(template, '(@)([[:alnum:]]+)(@)', '${\2}') as new_template
from data;

TEMPLATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NEW_TEMPLATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@ @@ ABC @variable1@ DEF @something2@ GHI @variable3@ @@@
@ @@ ABC ${variable1} DEF ${something2} GHI ${variable3} @@@
```